# Replace RegEx occurrences Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string in Java like this:

```
REF([123],[456],[78]),REF([789],[456],[12]),{111},REF([8069],[8098],[56])
```

I need to remove all the third occurring digits inside all the REFs. Meaning I need to remove [78], [12] and [56] (starting from the second comma till before  the closing brackets) from the string so that I get this following output:

```
REF([123],[456]),REF([789],[456]),{111},REF([8069],[8098])
```

What should my regex be?

Comment: Could there ever be four numbers in a REF, and if so, what should happen then?

Comment: There can not be a fourth number inside REF, Tim. Also REF could also exists as "ref" or "Ref", being case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String result = subject.replaceAll(
    "(?xi)(      # Match and capture in group 1:\n" +
    "REF\\(      # REF(\n" +
    "\\[\\d+\\], # a number in brackets, comma,\n" +
    "\\[\\d+\\]  # a number in brackets\n" +
    ")           # End of capturing group\n" +
    ",\\[\\d+\\] # Match a comma and a third number in brackets", "$1");
```

Comment: Love the comments mode, haven't seen that before.

Comment: This is a precise and elegant solution. Beautifully explained as well. Thank you very much Tim.